# How do i give default date format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to make my code more dry and neat  hence i used following in my "config/enviornment.rb":

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%M/%y"
```

But not saw any change in date format.Then i try "strftime" method but it doesn't suit my code.Please guide me on some better option .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the I18n for that.

config/locales/en.yml:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%M/%y"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

Then use `I18n.l Time.now` (or `<%= l Time.now %>`in your views).

**EDIT:** To specify the format, use `<%= l Time.now, :format => :short %>`

Comment: Yep, it's best to avoid doing `strftime` in the code, as this binds you to either using a single culture, or re-inventing the code that allows you to switch, which is provided in `I18n`.

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to put same line on every time i used to display date.